# How to add AjaxLink in Wicket ListView?

Tags: listview, hyperlink, wicket, java-ee-6, populate

I want to populate `AjaxLink` in `ListView`, and I have smth like:

```
list = Arrays.asList(new String[]{
        new String("1-50"),
        new String("50-100"),
        new String("100-150"),});
listItems = new ListView("your-list-view", list) {

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(final ListItem li) {

        li.add(new AjaxLink("label", li.getModel()){

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                System.out.println("AJAX WORKS");    
            }
         });
    }
};
```

and markup:

```
<ul>
    <li wicket:id="your-list-view"><a href="#" wicket:id="label"></a></li>
</ul>
```

But I have just an empty page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The < a> tags are empty here:

```
<li wicket:id="your-list-view"><a href="#" wicket:id="label"></a></li>
```

There is no text to click on. Add some text:

```
<li wicket:id="your-list-view"><a href="#" wicket:id="label">Link</a></li>
```

or a label:

```
<li wicket:id="your-list-view">
    <a href="#" wicket:id="label"><span wicket:id="linklabel"></span></a>
</li>
```

with java

```
@Override
protected void populateItem(final ListItem li) {
    AjaxLink alink = new AjaxLink("label", li.getModel()) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            System.out.println("AJAX WORKS");    
        }
     };
     alink.add(new Label("linklabel", "Yes ajax works!"));
     li.add(alink);
}
```

Comment: when i put some text in between `<a></a>` tags manually, it works. But when I tried to use your second method with attaching `label`, I have an error:`Last cause: Unable to find component with id 'linklabel' in [AjaxLink [Component id = label]]`

Comment: one bracket was wrong. I added the label to the list item in stead of of to the ajaxlink. I changed my answer and the code should work now. I now add the label to the ajaxlink because the label is inside the < a> tags.